# Is there a determinant rule for adding rows of ANOTHER matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Undergrad linear algebra 1 ~

I'm aware of the following three rules; each for an elementary operation:
*Note || denotes determinant; I find it kind of confusing with abs but that's what the book says.

E1: if the matrix B is A but with rows swapped, $|B|=-|A|$

E2: if the matrix B is A but a row is a multiple $k$ of another, $|B|=k|A|$

E3: if the matrix B is A but a multiple of another row is added/subtracted to another, $|B| = |A|$

However, I came across this question to find the determinant of $C$ given $det A = 3$ and $det B = -2$:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
e&f\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
2a-e&2b-f\\
3c&3d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I was able to solve it by the "usual way" of just multiplying $(2a-e)(3d)-(3c)(2b-f)$ because it's a simple 2 by 2, but I was wondering if there would be a way to use the logic of the elementary ops to "remove row 1 of matrix B from the matrix C" such that then matrix C has rows that are just scalar multiples of A, so then I can easily apply the E2 rule.

Comment: This is the multilinearity of the determinant as a function of its rows.

Comment: I have a feeling that's something I haven't covered; I'm going to search it up but could you give a very brief description? (I'm in the first/intro linear algebra class of undergrad)

Comment: I think you do need to do it in the usual way and then maybe see if you can write this determinant equation using those for $A$ and $B$. Although $C=MA+NB$ for some matrices $M,N$ there is usually no way of 'splitting' this sum. So it is a good question to think about

Comment: The appearance of $-2,3$ for determinants and then when row operations are performed is likely what makes the answer bellow to work. So the answer to your question  is 'not in general'

Answer (score 1):

Now write the determinant as $$\det{C}=6(ad-bc)+3(cf-ed)=12$$ (from your expression for the determinant of $C$).